# LMV324 particular characteristic?

Tags: amplifier

Our prof. at the university asked why the LMV324 is particular. Which is the characteristic that made this component so common in the modern electronics. He was talking about the ring gain or something like that, but I’m not sure if the answer is in there.
My question is: in your opinion, which is the main characteristic of this amplifier and more important how was designed (the scheme solution adopted)?

Maybe is something related with PMRR

Comment: TI [says](http://www.ti.com/product/lmv324) that "these amplifiers are designed specifically for low-voltage (2.7 V to 5 V) operation, with performance specifications meeting or exceeding the LM358 and LM324 devices that operate from 5 V to 30 V." Are you sure he asked about the LM**V**324 and not the LM324?

Comment: *Maybe is something related with PMRR* What do you mean? Perhaps you mean PSRR? The prof's question is **vague**. The fact that a certain IC is used a lot often has to do with **its design** but also with **price, availability, manufacturer reputation, competitor's ICs etc**. So the LM324 series might simply be "lucky". There are no doubt other similar comparators that can do the same job just as well. But many use the LM324 so many others do so as well.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416898/lmv324-benefit-of-double-retroaction-ring?noredirect=1#comment1031881_416898

Comment: The input range includes Ground. It has short-circuit protection to Ground. You can get FOUR per package. Tolerates enormous differential inputs, which is one feature of those PNP input devices. Delightful to use, if the UA709 was your first opamp.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf take a look at the link in the previous comment

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the LMV324 is common. It is almost rail to rail, but it is uncommon. The LM324 (and LM358) are common. They are low power, and can work on single ended supply. It also goes closer to ground than the LMV324.

The selling point of a component is often found in bold letters near the top of the front page in the datasheet.

*added*

The datasheet schematic shows a mosfet tied to positive rail, which helps it to achieve a higher output voltage than the LM324. This is a specialty for the LMV324 opamp.

The LMV324 has CMRR and PSRR of 65 and 60 db. The LM324 has 85 and 100 db. So LM324 is clearly better. Output low for LMV324 is 65 mv (180 mv max). For LM324 is 5 mV (20 mV max). So again LM324 is better. This makes the LM324 desirable and extremely common. The price is also low.

Only thing LMV324 can do is get to 10 mV of Vcc, while LM324 needs about 2 V (1.5 V typical) headroom. This is not generally an important enough requirement to sacrifice lower output low voltage. The LMV324 thus costs about 10 times as much, and is not common.

However, the most important practical difference between the LMV324 and LM324 is probably the 4th point on the LMV324 datasheet.... low crossover distortion. Lack of proper biasing in the LM324 output transistors leads to a small crossover distortion. The feedback in the LMV324 reduces this.

Comment: But why is the LMV324 important? Which characteristic was implemented in its scheme?

Comment: You didn't provide any answer for the question, so this should be posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @PeterVogric Like I said, the LMV324 output is rail to rail, but the op amp is not common. The datasheet schematic shows a mosfet tied to positive rail, which helps it to achieve a higher output voltage than the LM324.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The basic premise of the original question was wrong. The component is not "common in modern electronics". I have edited my answer to reflect the updated question.