# LMV324 benefit of double feedback?

Tags: amplifier

What is the benefit of the double feedback of the LMV324 op. Amp.? Why was that implemented in that way?

From this scheme I have to understand why was implemented in that way
[image]

[image]

Comment: Drive strength?

Comment: What does "double retroaction ring" mean? Can you indicate the portion of circuitry in question?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the prof. said this: what is the benefit of a double retroaction ring...

Comment: @PeterVogric Okay, from French translation it seems "retroaction" = "feedback".

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes, actually I mean double feedback

Comment: There is internal feedback for unity-gain compensation and external feedback, is that what the prof is referring to?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes, what is the benefit of that double feedback...

Comment: @PeterVogric The feedback reduces the crossover distortion, which is the second main difference between the LM324 and LMV324.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of the most challenging tasks to design a high-gain amplifier for frequencies down to zero Hz (that means: DC). The reason is that in this case, we cannot use coupling capacitors between the several stages (which would allow us to design and stabilize each stage separately). Each DC offset of one stage will act as an unwanted input for the following stage.

Therefore, it is absolutely neccessary to DC stabilize each stage using internal DC feedback. That means: It is a stabilization against an unwanted shift of the **DC operating point** - not against oscillation! In contrary - each feedback reduces the phase margin; that is the price we have to pay for a stable DC operating point.

Now, we have a high-gain DC amplifier and we want to realize the final gain value. For this purpose, we must use an external overall negative feedback loop (from the output to the inverting input). Again, this feedback loop will reduce the overall phase margin - and to avoid oscillation the amplifiers internal frequency response must satisfy some specific requirements...but this is not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The internal feedback is to stabilize the amplifier so it does not oscillate and has reasonable phase margin for any external gain.

Typically with an op-amp the (compensated) open-loop gain will start to drop at around 10Hz and will drop by 6dB/octave (single dominant pole). The series resistor will have a small effect- the gain won't drop as much at frequencies approaching around 1MHz.

Comment: OP: You might want to wait a bit longer (24 hours is good) before accepting an answer. Much more detailed answers are possible. You can un-accept.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second (external) feedback?

Comment: The second (external) feedback sets the overall behavior- closed-loop gain, for example, or filter characteristics. You can, to a degree, ignore the internal feedback and assume an ideal op-amp until the open-loop gain drops to the point where it has a significant effect on the behavior. For example, if the closed loop gain is nominally -100  you might be able to operate to about 5 or 10kHz before the closed loop gain is affected too much (since unity gain bandwidth is 1MHz for this amplifier).